# Temperature using Sentinel 3 in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel, sentinel-3

I am trying to find information on how to obtain surface temperature layers - LST - from Sentinel 3 on Google Earth Engine but I am not getting anywhere. Is there any method to do it?

The Sentinel 3 bands are:

[image]

If this is not possible, which platform do you recommend for the LST calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this within GEE, as the only Sentinel-3 instrument available is the OLCI (as shown in your screenshot). There are several sensors onboard the Sentinel-3, and the instrument you need for LST calculations is from the SLSTR, as detailed on the ESA website:
https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-3-slstr/overview/geophysical-measurements/land-surface-temperature

If you specifically want Sentinel-3 LST data, you can download it via the Copernicus Hub: https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home
However, if you want to use GEE, I suggest you look at the MODIS LST dataset, as it might have what you are looking for.

For starters, here's a script to calculate a MODIS LST time series:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/8962083b37bb3046f1ccb2d19ae3cc37?noload=true

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know why S3 SLSTR is not on GEE?